# How to choose which files to open directly in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

For some files, chrome will download it while others it will open it directly in chrome. Is there any setting I can use to choose what kinds of files to open in chrome directly ?

Comment: That depends on the content-disposition header set by the website. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-files-to-open-in-browser-instead-of-download-pdf and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251575/how-to-ignore-content-disposition-attachment-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

@spherical_dog is right.That depends on the `content-disposition` header. The header is set by the server. So, you (the client) can do nothing about it.

But as far as i know, if `content-disposition` header is not set by the server, chrome only opens `.txt`, `.pdf` and sometimes image files automatically inside it.

There is no specific settings for this but you can try the following things:

1. If you try to disable built-in pdf viewer, enter, "chrome:plugins" in the address bar, then click the Disable link under the "Chrome PDF Viewer" plugin entry. By this way, you can download pdf files always without viewing them in chrome
2. There is a method by which you can open specific file types automatically (not inside chrome but inside default viewer for that file type) right after it finishes downloading. Download a file. Click the arrow that appears on the file that appears at the bottom of your screen and select "Always open files of this type". From later on, if you download same file type, chrome will open it automatically for you.

**update**

There is a chrome extension that helps you to inject custom headers in response headers. click here to check [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en). Here you can set `content-disposition` value to `attachment`. It will download the file automatically.
**IMPORTANT:** Use `filter` tab in this extension to filter where to apply this custom header. You can create a filter that will allow only pdf files to be downloaded. Without filter, if you use it, it will download everything. even web pages.

It's not really a solution, but just to inform you that it is also possible.